# Multiple, unknown number of fields passed into a query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Is it possible to create a generic query that would work for different types of documents? For example I have "cases" and "factories",
They have different set of fields. e.g:

```
{
    id: 'case_o1',
    name: 'Case numero uno',
    amount: 40
}

{
   id: 'factory_002',
   location: 'Venezuela',
   workers: 200,
   operating: true
}
```

Is it possible to create a generic query where I would pass the type of an entity (case or factory) and additional parameters and it would filter results based on those?
I could of course use javascript view, but it doesn't allow me to filter by multiple fields. Let's say I want to fetch all factories located in Venezuela, with number of workers between 20 and 55.

I started with this, but then I got stuck:

```
select * from `mybucket` as entity
where position(meta(entity).id, $entity_type) == 0
```

How do I pass multiple predicates and have the query to recognize them?

I can of course list fields like this:

```
where position(meta(entity).id, $entity_type) == 0  
and entity.location == 'Venezuela'
and entity.workers > $workers_min
and entity.workers < $workers_max
```

but then

- I'm gonna have to create a separate query for each entity
- And even then it won't solve my problem - I have no idea how to ignore predicates, what if next time $workers_min and $workers_max are not passed, does it mean I have to create a query for every single predicate (column)?
- For security reasons I cannot generate free-form queries and pass them to Couchbase server, all the queries are already stored in the database, our api just picks them up out of a document and executes them
- I think it's possible to create a query that would be "short-circuiting" for args that's undefined (e.g.  `WHERE $location IS MISSING OR entity.location == $location` or something like that)

**Is it possible at all to create a query that would be able to effectively filter and order a dataset based on arbitrary parameters? Or there's no way?**

Comment: Of course, you can build your query programmatically based on any logic you want. In other words, if you can do it for SQL, you can do it for N1QL.

Comment: @geraldss we decided not to pass any queries to couchbase directly, for security reasons. All all queries are stored in the DB itself. Now I need to build a query that would be able to parse all incoming parameters if it's possible

Comment: For SQL I did https://github.com/bitifet/sqlapi …I know nothing about nql, but seems it should'nt be difficult to adapt… (sorry for below comment, I'm writting from my phone and found this post again too late to fix it)

Comment: @bitifet again, I cannot build queries on the fly and pass them to the server. I need to have a query that would be sitting in the database document.

Comment: @bitifet, your API would probably work with N1QL, which is just a SQL dialect. Agzam, you may need a separate query for each entity. As for parameters, use the pattern you described, where the param either matches the input or the input is missing.

Answer (score 1):

@Agzam. Sorry. I were writting my comment when you said it. But anyway. What you are asking for is possible by using coalesces in a not too complex expressions, but it is a REALLY bad idea because this will drastically throw down most of internal database optimizations. Including the use of any existing index. So, except if you are dealing with a relatively small database (and you are sure it will remain being approximately the same size), I suggest you to better try distinct approach… This is, in fact, the reason I implmented sqlapi.

If you need to have all querys previously stored in database, it probably could be much better to sort given arguments by its name and precalculate and store precalculated querys for each possible combination.

Comment: Sorry. I would post a comment, not an answer (again from phone). I apologize for that, but the app is preventing me to copy the text to paste it in a comment.

Comment: I know. I'm seeing it happening already. Regardless of query's complexity querying the database takes way too long without indexes. As I suspected in the beginning and it still looks that way - the only viable way to build normal search is to have something alongside Couchbase server cluster. like Elasticsearch.

Comment: I'm very frustrated with N1QL. It's not ready for production use. Tooling is very primitive, documentation and api very poor. It does not solve problems it was promised to, and it creates false sense of alternative to views.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by assigning a default value to the variable when is not used. For instance if $location is not used you can set it to -1 as default value.
Then the where condition would be:

```
WHERE ($location=-1 OR entity.location = $location)
```

Comment: Couchbase I believe will complain `No value for named parameter $location` if it's not passed. I couldn't find a way to have a check for if parameter exists (passed in) or not. I still have to pass all params, most of them would be `= null`, only those that matter would have values, but you still have to pass all `$` params to query